# PHP MySqli Delete error message

Tags: php, mysqli

This code does delete a record from the table correctly but the second time run on the same table it still reports "Record deleted successfully". Why is that?

```
 // sql to delet a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM setidata WHERE  SETIData_ID=834";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
echo "<br> Finished";
?>
```

Comment: Use `mysqli_affected_rows()`. I.e.: `if (mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0) {...} else{...}`

Answer (score 1):

Because mysqli_query returns true not matter if the record exists or not.
use  mysqli_affected_rows();  to see how many rows have been deleted.

```
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)==0){
        print "Nothing done";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks all for this answer. It seem strange to me but knowing how it works is important.

Comment: mysqli_query($conn, $sql) only returns false if your query contains errors. You query doesn't have any errors. If you changed the sql to something like $sql = "DELETEXX FROM setidata WHERE  SETIData_ID=834"; It wil return an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)` is returning true since since there were no errors triggered by the query or in the function mysqli_query(). If you want to do something redundant, mysqli_query() will not stop you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code If query is succesful then it will echo as opted. You can run this query in phpmyadmin->SQL. First time it will show deleted rows 1. Next time it will show 0.